# keep the first row and change the rest of values to NaN in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [
            'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',
        ],
        'b': [
            -20, 20, 20, 20,-70, -70,-11, -100, -1, -1, -100, 100
        ],
        'c': [
            'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'x', 'x', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k'
        ],
        'x': [
            'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'x', 'x', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i'
        ],
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
    a     b    c  x
0   a -20.0    f  p
1   a   NaN  NaN  p
2   a   NaN  NaN  p
3   a   NaN  NaN  p
4   a   NaN  NaN  p
5   a   NaN  NaN  x
6   b -11.0    x  x
7   b   NaN  NaN  i
8   b   NaN  NaN  i
9   b   NaN  NaN  i
10  b   NaN  NaN  i
11  b   NaN  NaN  i
```

For each group in column `a` I want to keep only the first row and change the rest of values to `nan`. Note that in my real data I don't know the index of columns. I may have hundreds of columns that I need to keep their first row and change the rest to `nan`.

And This is what I have tried. I don't know if it is ok. Should I do this hundred times if I have 100 columns?!!!

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

def func(g):
    g.iloc[1:, g.columns.get_loc('b')] = np.nan
    g.iloc[1:, g.columns.get_loc('c')] = np.nan
    return g

df = df.groupby('a', as_index=False).apply(func)
```

I used `get_loc` because I don't know the exact index of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, you can modify your grouping function to use `.columns.difference`:

```py
def fn(g):
    g.loc[g.index[1] :, g.columns.difference(["a", "x"])] = np.nan
    return g


out = df.groupby("a", group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    a     b    c  x
0   a -20.0    f  p
1   a   NaN  NaN  p
2   a   NaN  NaN  p
3   a   NaN  NaN  p
4   a   NaN  NaN  p
5   a   NaN  NaN  x
6   b -11.0    x  x
7   b   NaN  NaN  i
8   b   NaN  NaN  i
9   b   NaN  NaN  i
10  b   NaN  NaN  i
11  b   NaN  NaN  i
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why you used `group_keys`? The output is same with or without it.

Comment: @x_Amir_x What pandas version do you use? Without `group_keys=False` the final dataframe has two index columns (one index column is named `a`)

Comment: It is 1.2 on this machine. I probably need to upgrade it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df.where(~df['a'].duplicated()).fillna(df[['a', 'x']])
```

Using `pd.DataFrame.where` and `pd.Dataframe.fillna` and index alignment to fill the columns you want data.

Output:

```
    a     b    c  x
0   a -20.0    f  p
1   a   NaN  NaN  p
2   a   NaN  NaN  p
3   a   NaN  NaN  p
4   a   NaN  NaN  p
5   a   NaN  NaN  x
6   b -11.0    x  x
7   b   NaN  NaN  i
8   b   NaN  NaN  i
9   b   NaN  NaN  i
10  b   NaN  NaN  i
11  b   NaN  NaN  i
```